# [javascript][iterable object] How to sum up the specific key's value in iterable object like array

Tags: javascript, arraylist, javascript-objects

How to sum up the specific key's value in iterable object like array  while the specific key can be nested inside an object key.
example:
how can I do the sum of the key value whose key name is val?

```
var list = {
val: 5,
child1: {
  val : 10,
  someotherKey: 'somevalue'
},
child2: {
  val : 20,
  someotherKey2: 'someothervalue
},
child3: {
  someval: {
  val: 15,
  somekey3: 'somevalue3'
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with for in loop like
for( key in list) {

```
 for(key in list) {
  if(key === 'val') {
  console.log(key);
  }
  if(list[key]['val']) {
    console.log(key);
   }
  }
```

but couldn't reach the solution.

Comment: how deeply might the `val` keys be nested?   Just one level, or an arbtirary number?

Comment: p.s. there's no iterable array in your data

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.reduce()`, The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array to reduce it to a single value.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion and keep on adding the value to sum

```js
let sum = 0;
 var list = {
val: 5,
child1: {
  val : 10,
  someotherKey: 'somevalue'
},
child2: {
  val : 20,
  someotherKey2: 'someothervalue'
},
child3: {
  someval: {
  val: 15,
  somekey3: 'somevalue3'
    }
  }
}
function addVal(obj){
  if(obj.val) {
   sum+=obj.val;
 }
 Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
   if(typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
    addVal(obj[key])
  }
 })
}

addVal(list);
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer using recursion.

Comment: @SiddharthRay , if it satisfies, can you accept as answer?

Comment: I don't have authorization to do it. Less than 15 reputation can't vote. sry for that.